# How to create `FeatureCollection` of `FeatureCollection` on Google Earth Engine for efficient merge?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a list of `FeatureCollection` of points in Google Earth Engine that I would like to merge into a single `FeatureCollection`, the [documentation on `merge`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-featurecollection-merge) says that one should make a collection of collections then use `.flatten`.

> Note: If many collections need to be merged, consider placing them all
> in a collection and using FeatureCollection.flatten() instead.
> Repeated use of FeatureCollection.merge() will result in increasingly
> long element IDs and reduced performance.

But the API doesn't seem to provide a mechanism to turn a list of `FeatureCollection`s into a single `FeatureCollection`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply call `ee.FeatureCollection()` with the list to convert it to a `FeatureCollection`. This works for any list of features or feature-like values (features, collections, images).

```js
var listOfFC = ee.List([
  ee.FeatureCollection([ee.Feature(null, {'x': 1})]),
  ee.FeatureCollection([ee.Feature(null, {'x': 2})]),
  ee.FeatureCollection([ee.Feature(null, {'x': 3})]),
  ee.FeatureCollection([ee.Feature(null, {'x': 4})]),
]);

print(ee.FeatureCollection(listOfFC).flatten());
```