# Getting imagery in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, clip, sentinel-2

Is it OK to flatten several features into a single one before obtaining the raster data?

I have several AOIs in the form of GeoJSON files. I open them using

```
AOI01 = geemap.geojson_to_ee('path/to/AOI01.geojson')
...
AOI0n = geemap.geojson_to_ee('path/to/AOI0n.geojson')
```

*Note: I am positive that all the GeoJSON files are good, and can be visualized correctly on the map.*

Now I need to create a Sentinel raster from each of the AOIs. I usually use `.filterBounds(AOI)` when calling `ee.ImageCollection`. But now I have several AOIs and I thought it would be more convenient to merge all AOI into a single one, and then use it, eg. `.filterBounds(All_my_AOIs)` instead of calling n times to my `ee.ImageCollection` using each of the individual AOIs. Makes sense?

Thus I merged my AOIs using advice from [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/427747/how-to-create-featurecollection-of-featurecollection-on-google-earth-engine) like this:

```
ListOfAOIs = ee.List([AOI01, AOI02, ..., AOIn])
All_my_AOIs = ee.FeatureCollection(ListOfAOIs).flatten()
```

Then I proceed as usual using

```
SentinelImages = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")\
                      .filterDate(date_range)\
                      .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE','less_than', 25)\
                      .filterBounds(All_my_AOIs)
```

Using this approach I get almost 2000 images (inspected using `SentinelImages.size()`), after which I select the first image and clip it to my first AOI:

```
AOI_raster = SentinelImages.first().clip(AOI01)
```

However, when I try to show AOI_raster on a map, I get nothing.

Comment: Did you try without flatten()?

Comment: oh you mean `All_my_AOIs = ee.FeatureCollection(ListOfAOIs)`?

Comment: Yes, you can test whether the flatten has any effect

Comment: If I don't use flatten, then I get exception when trying to add the `AOI_raster` to my map: `EEException: Collection.geometry: Unable to use a collection in an algorithm that requires a feature or image. This may happen when trying to use a collection of collections where a collection of features is expected; use flatten, or map a function to convert inner collections to features. Use clipToCollection (instead of clip) to clip an image to a collection.`

Comment: Okay. Did you inspect `Map.centreObject(AOI01)`, may be missing the area. In addition, following the error, you can try `SentinelImages.first().clipToCollection(All_my_AOIs)` while keeping the flatten().

Comment: if I use `SentinelImages.first().clipToCollection(All_my_AOIs)` I don't get an error, but it takes forever when I try to show it on a map. Something must be wrong..

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any issue here. If you use `.filterBounds(All_my_AOIs)` on the image collection, you shouldn't expect that the `.first()` image (or any single image) will cover every single feature. Simple example: https://code.earthengine.google.com/a9ebcde12d88df00aae19a3c3540254a

Comment: Thanks Oliver. I may be misunderstanding some things. I was assuming that the 'first' means the first image of my temporal range, I never realized that the image collection is also spatially 'divided'. But then, how would I access the first (temporally speaking) image? And how is the "first" (spatially) defined? Northwest clockwise? I need to learn more about this...

Comment: `.first()` gives you the first image in the collection, which depends on how you sort the image collection (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-imagecollection-sort). You are using Sentinel 2 images, each one covers about 110km x 110km:  https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/missions/sentinel-2/data-products